# How do I Keep letters and symbols stay in one spot after they are printed in c++?

Tags: c++

[How the code looks printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS1WS.png)

[How I want the code to look when printed(not the numbers just the colon:)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXFjP.png)

**Different ways I have tried to keep the colon from moving**\

```
printf("COURSE GRADE   : POINTS NEEDED ON FINAL      : PERCENTAGE NEEDED ON FINAL\n");
 printf("A              : %d                          : %5.2f%%\n", neededA, percentA);
 printf("B              : %d                         %c %5.2f%%\n", neededB, 58, percentB);
 printf("C %14c %d %24c %5.2f%%\n", 58, neededC, 58, percentC);
 printf("D              : %d                         %0c %5.2f%%\n", neededD, 58, percentD);
```

Comment: YOUR SHIFT KEY SEEMS TO BE STUCK. YOU MIGHT WANT TO INVEST IN A NEW KEYBOARD. WE REALLY DON'T LIKE TO BE SHOUTED AT HERE - IT'S REALLY RUDE AND ANNOYING. IT'S EVEN WORSE WHEN YOU **SHOUT IN BOLD AS WELL**, BECAUSE IT SHOWS YOU'RE TRYING TO **SHOUT EVEN LOUDER**. Please lower your voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using printf you should read up what the format specifier can do. Because it can do what you want.

```
printf("%20d\n", 42);
```

Will make sure the field that is printed is at least 20 glyphs wide.
While positive integer like 20 will result in a right-justified field using a negative integer results in a left-justified filed.